# Avoiding CAPTCHA when cutting and pasting on stackexchange sites?

Tags: support, captcha

I often writeup my stackexchange questions in emacs (as God intended), 
and then cut/paste them to the webform when I'm ready.

Problem: stackexchange sees the cut/paste as a spam attempt(?) and 
makes me type a CAPTCHA.

Not a huge deal, but is there a way around this?

It seems to me any halfway-intelligent spammer would use curl or 
something similar to submit forms directly. Does flagging 
cut-and-paste really help that much?

Comment: I wonder if using vi would've given you upvotes...

Comment: @balpha I was really confused why this got so many downvotes; it didn't seem *that* crazy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you composed an entire post in the blink of an eye -- think about how that looks to a website.

Maybe just pause a bit before submitting.

Answer (score 4):

If you use Firefox you might find the [It's All Text!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4125/) add-on useful. It adds an edit button to text areas that launches your editor, and when you're done you save in the editor and it imports the text into the text area. I don't know how SO's cut-and-paste detector works, but I used to use that add-on all the time and never ran into a problem

Comment: Or if the add-on is somehow not usable, then maybe just typing a single character on the website when starting to compose a post in some other tool, might help too?